# Where's the alarm widget on my new HTC One m8?

Tags: app-widgets, htc-one-x, htc

I just "upgraded" to a HTC One M8 from a Galaxy S3 and I can't see how to add the alarm home-screen widget.

On the S3 there's the '2 x 1 Alarm' widget which is great. How do I add this to my M8 please?

Also, is the disappearance of this due to a newer version of Android or is this widget only available on Samsung phones?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it right: It's probably a Samsung-specific widget.

Answer (score 1):

As you've suggested, this is a Samsung-only widget. You can easily find equivalents on Google Play if you want one; perhaps you'll even find something you like better than your old Samsung widget.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Samsung-specific widget. I would suggest you to install other apps from Play Store with same functionality. You can give [Timely Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely) a try.